# Docker. Can not execute copied files from host to image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Dawid Stec <dawid.stec@gmail.com>
LABEL Description="Docker image for building arm-embedded"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  git \
  cmake \
  make \
  automake \
  libffi-dev \
  libssl-dev \
  libusb-1.0.0 \
  libusb-1.0.0-dev \
  software-properties-common \
  ccache

COPY toolchain /home/tools

ENV PATH="/home/tools/bin:${PATH}"
```

then I create image:

```
sudo docker build -t lpc-arm .
```

and login into image:

```
docker run -i -t lpc-arm /bin/bash
```

In running container I see copied files.

```
root@58f75da4406c:/home/tools/bin# ls
arm-none-eabi-addr2line  arm-none-eabi-c++filt  arm-none-eabi-gcc        arm-none-eabi-gcc-ranlib  arm-none-eabi-gdb-py  arm-none-eabi-nm       arm-none-eabi-readelf
arm-none-eabi-ar         arm-none-eabi-cpp      arm-none-eabi-gcc-5.4.1  arm-none-eabi-gcov        arm-none-eabi-gprof   arm-none-eabi-objcopy  arm-none-eabi-size
arm-none-eabi-as         arm-none-eabi-elfedit  arm-none-eabi-gcc-ar     arm-none-eabi-gcov-tool   arm-none-eabi-ld      arm-none-eabi-objdump  arm-none-eabi-strings
arm-none-eabi-c++        arm-none-eabi-g++      arm-none-eabi-gcc-nm     arm-none-eabi-gdb         arm-none-eabi-ld.bfd  arm-none-eabi-ranlib   arm-none-eabi-strip
```

but when I try to execute **arm-none-eabi-gcc** I'm getting error:

```
root@58f75da4406c:/home/tools/bin# ./arm-none-eabi-gcc
bash: ./arm-none-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory
```

I should be able to execute this program, but why I can't?

Command in host: **ls -lrs toolchain/**

```
4 drwxr-xr-x 4 solitech solitech   4096 wrz 24 14:21 share
  4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 solitech solitech   4056 lip 21  2016 release.txt
  4 drwxr-xr-x 3 solitech solitech   4096 wrz 24 14:21 redlib
 16 -rwxr-xr-x 1 solitech solitech  13523 lip 21  2016 readme.txt
176 -rwxr-xr-x 1 solitech solitech 178692 lip 21  2016 license.txt
  4 drwxr-xr-x 3 solitech solitech   4096 wrz 24 14:21 lib
  4 drwxr-xr-x 3 solitech solitech   4096 wrz 24 14:21 features
  4 drwxr-xr-x 2 solitech solitech   4096 wrz 24 14:21 bin
  4 drwxr-xr-x 6 solitech solitech   4096 wrz 24 14:21 arm-none-eabi
```

and in image:

```
  4 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 Sep 24 12:21 share
  4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4056 Jul 21  2016 release.txt
  4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Sep 24 12:21 redlib
 16 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  13523 Jul 21  2016 readme.txt
176 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 178692 Jul 21  2016 license.txt
  4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Sep 24 12:21 lib
  4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Sep 24 12:21 features
  4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Sep 24 12:21 bin
  4 drwxr-xr-x 6 root root   4096 Sep 24 12:21 arm-none-eabi
```

Image is available at: `xandareva/lpc-arm`. You can pull it and test yourself.

Comment: Make the file executable, then rebuild the container

Comment: try execute it by absolute path

Comment: what's the output of `ls -lrs toolchain/` in the host and in the guest?

Comment: @cricket_007 not working.

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko not working.

Comment: Your Dockerfile is less readable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that output as a formatted code block

Comment: Added `ls -lrs toolchain/` response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run 32-bit executable on a 64-bit architecture:

```
root@8ccee441d384:/home/tools/bin# file arm-none-eabi-gcc
arm-none-eabi-gcc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 
(SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for 
GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped
```

You need to add `i386` architecture,
and the `libc6:i386`, `libncurses5:i386`, `libstdc++6:i386` library packages:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

After installing these packages, I managed to run the binary:

```
root@8ccee441d384:/home/tools/bin# ./arm-none-eabi-gcc
arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

For more information about this, check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists

Comment: It helps. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that arm-none-eabi-gcc is a binary built for arm architecture, while you are trying to exec it in a x86-64 container.

Try to change the base image to https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/ubuntu/ or another with the needed architecture. Here you have some links to those images: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64